# PHP for loop within for loop with different incrementing values

Tags: php, loops

I am new to PHP and for loops but I am having trouble racking my brain around the math for this.  I am trying to write a loop that will create an array with 49 items.  The items have two incrementing values within them.  The 49 items are below:

```
M1s1t1url
M1s1t2url
M1s1t3url
M1s1t4url
M1s1t5url
M1s1t6url
M1s1t7url
M1s2t1url
M1s2t2url
M1s2t3url
M1s2t4url
M1s2t5url
M1s2t6url
M1s2t7url
M1s3t1url
M1s3t2url
M1s3t3url
M1s3t4url
M1s3t5url
M1s3t6url
M1s3t7url
M1s4t1url
M1s4t2url
M1s4t3url
M1s4t4url
M1s4t5url
M1s4t6url
M1s4t7url
M1s5t1url
M1s5t2url
M1s5t3url
M1s5t4url
M1s5t5url
M1s5t6url
M1s5t7url
M1s6t1url
M1s6t2url
M1s6t3url
M1s6t4url
M1s6t5url
M1s6t6url
M1s6t7url
M1s7t1url
M1s7t2url
M1s7t3url
M1s7t4url
M1s7t5url
M1s7t6url
M1s7t7url
```

As you can see there are three numbers in each item.  The first number is a constant.  The second number counts up to 7 then resets back to 1.  The third number adds 1 every time the second number resets back to 1.  Here is what I have below but I know I am off on the calculations.

```
   for ($i = 1; $i < 8; $i = $i + 1) {
        for ($u = 1; $u < 8; $u = $u + 1) {
            $urln[] = 'M1s'.[$u].'t'.[$i].'url';
        }
    }
```

I am getting an array to string error.

Comment: `$urln[] = 'M1s'.$u.'t'.$i.'url';`

Comment: In newer versions of PHP `[$u]` is equivalent to `array($u)`

Comment: @DavidFrank perfect!  I knew I was missing something silly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i < 8; $i++) {
    for ($u = 1; $u < 8; $u++) {
        $urln[] = 'M1s' . $u . 't' . $i . 'url';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $urln = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i < 8; $i++) {
        for ($u = 1; $u < 8; $u++) {
            $urln[] = 'M1s' .$i. 't'. $u .'url';
        }
    }

    foreach ($urln as $i) {
        echo "$i\n";
    }

?>
```